# Ways to traverse a graph, other than DFS and BFS?

Tags: graph-theory

Are there any ways to traverse a graph (directed or undirected) other than depth first search (DFS) and breadth first search (BFS)?

Comment: [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

In the generic graph traversal algorithm, one repeatedly explore an arc from an known vertex to another vertex. The difference between BFS and DFS is in the choice of which arc, at each step. BFS prioritizes an available arc from a vertex discovered as early as possible, while DFS prioritizes an available arc from a vertex discovered as late as possible.

These two choices of prioritization are arbitrary, as the algorithm would work for any possible order on the arcs. There are actually many algorithms that uses other orders. For instance, Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest weighted paths prioritizes an arc that will give a smallest distance to its destination, Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning trees prioritizes an arc with smallest weight. Even without arc weights, some variant exists, like Lexicographic BFS, which is a refinement of BFS in the sense that an arc chosen by LexBFS could have been chosen by BFS (but LexBFS is more restrictive).

BFS and DFS are particularly famous because of their wide range of applications. BFS is known to give the shortest non-weighted paths from a source $s$ and computing the distances from $s$, that fact alone make it useful in many applications. DFS is the root of backtracking algorithms, it also have properties that make it well-suited for some applications related to the connectivity of the graph, notably for topological sorting and the detection of strongly connected component (Tarjan's algorithm).